# permission denied while copying files with root

Tags: linux, root, cp

Ok, how is it possible that I get perm denied when I'm copying files in console. Any ideas?

Comment: is that in nfs? please provide more details....

Comment: ext3 is the filesystem. i just used cp -r / bakfolder

Comment: Which child of / gave the issue? Maybe try copying children one by one until you find it. I've had a similar issue with writing to files or directories associated with devices, but to get permission denied on just a read seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is not a file or a directory, please try `cp -r /* destination`

you might also consider to use `rsync` instead.